# Is is true that a proper subword cannot lie in the normal closure of a word?

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

Let $F$ be a free group and $w\in F$ a cyclically reduced word. Let $v$ be a non-trivial proper subword of $w$. Is it true that $v\notin \langle w^F\rangle$?

Comment: Actually, for context, there exist examples if, instead, one only assumes that $v$ is an arbitrary reduced word with $0<|v|<|w|$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1958310/35400 . Namely, $xzx^{-1}z^{-1}$ belongs to the normal closure of $x^2zxz$ (indeed $\langle x,z\mid x^2zxz\rangle$ is a disguised presentation of the cyclic group $\langle x,y\mid xy^2\rangle$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true.  See Theorem 2 of [ON RELATORS AND DIAGRAMS FOR GROUPS WITH ONE DEFINING RELATION
BY
C. M. WEINBAUM](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1215%2Fijm%2F1256052287&referringURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&isResultClick=False).

Comment: Actually this seems to be asked and answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957873/one-relator-groups-shortest-word-in-quotient