# Primitive elements in a free group with trivial projection

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups, primitive-elements

For a free group $F$, an element $w$ is primitive if it is part of some free basis for $F$.

Let $\pi:F[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]\rightarrow F[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ be defined $\pi (x_0)=1$ and $\pi (x_i)=x_i$ for $i\geq 1$.

My question is:

Is there an example of a cyclically reduced primitive element $w$ in $F[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$ satisfying $\pi(w)=1$ whose length is greater than 1?

[Added for clarification]

Note: if $w$ is an example, then there must be more than one occurrence of $x_0$ in $w$ and the exponent sum of $x_0$ in $w$ must be $\pm 1$.

Comment: There is a basis (xyzx^{-1}y^{-1}, xyz, y)$.

Comment: It is true that this is a basis., therefore each element is primitive. But I don't think it provides an example. I assume you are taking $x_0 = z$. In this case, after applying $\pi$ to your set, we get $\{ xyx^{-1}y^{-1},xy,y \}$.

Comment: Sorry, thanks!...

Comment: Do you know the answer for $n=1$?

Comment: @YCor For $n=1$ I think no such $w$ can exist, since in this case the image of $\pi$ is abelian, so $w$ would be of the form $x_0^\pm$ times a commutator, and then the fact that $Out(F_2)\cong GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ implies that $w$ is conjugate to $x_0^\pm$. But this doesn't work at all for $n>1$, since the image of $\pi$ is not abelian, and also there's a non-trivial Torelli group to worry about....

Comment: Here's an observation about the general case: Since $w$ is primitive, modding out the normal closure of either $w$ or $x_0$ yields a group isomorphic to $F_n$. Since $F_n$ is Hopfian, if $w$ is contained in the normal closure of $x_0$ (which is $\ker(\pi)$), then it must actually equal it. Said another way, if such a $w$ exists, then it must normally generate all of $\ker(\pi)$.

Comment: @Matt Zaremsky I think that would do it then. If $x_0 \in \langle \langle w\rangle \rangle$ and $w$ is cyclically reduced, we know from the recent discussion (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424715/is-is-true-that-a-proper-subword-cannot-lie-in-the-normal-closure-of-a-word) that $x_0$ cannot be a proper subword of $w$. So $w=x_0^{\pm 1}$. A very useful observation indeed!

Comment: @AndrewClifford Oh nice, yes, that does it. And it looks like now Giles has tied everything together quite nicely. (Honestly I'm a little surprised the answer turned out to be "no".)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there cannot be a primitive element $w \in \ker \pi$ that is not conjugate to $x_0$ or $x_0^{-1}$.

The map $\pi$ factors through $F[x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n] / \langle \langle w \rangle \rangle$, which is isomorphic to $F_n$ since $w$ is primitive. As the free group is Hopfian, this means the induced surjection $F[x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n] / \langle \langle w \rangle \rangle \to F_n$ is in fact an isomorphism, so $w$ and $x_0$ have the same normal closure in $F_{n+1}$. A theorem of Magnus from 1931, citing from Lyndon and Schupp's book "Combinatorial Group Theory", states:

**Proposition II.5.8.** If two elements $r_1$ and $r_2$ in a free group $F$ have the same normal closure in $F$, then $r_1$ is conjugate to $r_2$ or to $r_2^{-1}$.